# Antonym of "addressing" somebody (opposite of @ at)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, antonyms

We are working in teams on the same files. We developed a mechanism to add markers for oneself or to address other people with the following syntax (similar to the @ addressing mechanism here at the StackExchange networks):

```
//Bob: I need to remember this place and come back later (addressed oneself)
//Bob @ Alice: Please continue here or please fix this error
```

With the words of 1006a:

> So to put this in English, you currently have a notation that means
>   something like
>
> `Bob says to Alice: ...`
>
> but you want something that can be read:
>
> `Alice, Bob says: ...?`

In the tools we use there is a special view where everybody can see this "note". However for a better ordering we need to switch both names but want to keep the meaning. Is there an opposite symbol for the @ (at) sign? I didn't find any so a short word would also suffice. But all the words I can think of don't exactly match the meaning.

```
// Alice (by Bob): Please continue here or please fix this error
// Alice (from Bob): Please continue here or please fix this error
// Alice (addressed by Bob): Please continue here or please fix this error
```

The first two sound strange and the last one is too clumsy - isn't there a short version or an @ antonym symbol?
Unfortunately a leading @ (e.g. `//@Alice (by Bob) ...`) is not allowed since that would throw off the ordering. So the addressee name needs to come first.

Comment: There is no common answer to this. You are free to make up whatever convention you want. Personally, it looks to me as if you almost have anyway—with the parentheses. **// Bob @ Alice:** could be seen as semantically equivalent to **// Alice (Bob):**. Or forgo the parentheses and use something else graphically suggestive. **// Alice < Bob:**. But anything you do will be quite subjective—and have little to do with English.

Comment: @Lonzak stack exchange uses – to signify "from" in the comments and @ to signify "to" (but the ndash, mdash, hyphen confusion would discourage me from emulating this). Personally, I'd simplify further and just go with the traditional email version of To: and From:. Or do you require a single character? I'd rather match a string in code than require new team members to decrypt a team-specific alphabet.

Comment: Not a single symbol, but we use "Bob->Alice".

Comment: So to put this in English, you currently have a notation that means something like *Bob says to Alice:* but you want something that can be read *hey Alice, Bob says:*?

Comment: I suggest this has nothing to do with English. You are working in a language of your own construction, with your own rules. If they don't work then why not either use English, or change your invented language to match whatever constraints you need?

Comment: This is beside the point, but why can't you precede *all* the messages with a leading @?   If *every* message has it, the sort order will be the same.

Comment: @1006a Yes exactly.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Yes we could make up our own syntax like `Alice # Bob` but this is not self explanatory. We use our own conventions but the english language is the underlying base language so to speak. It should be as intuitive as possible which is the case for `Bob @ Alice` notation.

Comment: @Scott Good idea, but then we have to change the self-addressing syntax, too. (Which I want to avoid). It was hard to establish in the first place. Now we have all team members following it and I don't want to change that by changing the syntax again. One syntax change (the @) is enough...

Comment: 1. The commit log will indicate who wrote the line. 2. Consider using an issue tracker so that each `TODO` comment is not forgotten. 3. Source control typically offers the notion of integration review or pull request review; use these for your comments.

Comment: @Lonzak, *Bob @ Alice* is **not** intuitive. It would likely be read as 'Bob at Alice', which is meaningless outside a local convention that gives it meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caret (^) is sometimes used for a similar purpose, to identify the author of a tweet.

[Mashable said in 2013](https://mashable.com/2013/07/19/twitter-lingo-guide/?europe=true#r_zzLeAJdZqo): "The caret, or hat sign, is used to denote a tweet composed and sent by an individual on behalf of a group account used by multiple people (often a company or organization) account. It usually appears at the end of a Tweet and precedes initials, to indicate which user sent the tweet (e.g., ^JS)." Wikipedia calls this a "Signature tag" (in the [Caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret#Signature_tag) article): "a caret placed before a word is used to tag that word as an individual's signature".

[Some people say](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-symbol-in-Twitter-mean) the caret is used because it looks like a hat, and hence in the sense of hat tip (used to acknowledge a source), but I don't know if this is a folk etymology.

Comment: Thank you! This might have been what I have been looking for. So it could look like this `// Alice: Please continue here or please fix this error (^Bob)`

Answer (score 2):

The [@tention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign), in some cases, @ is used for "attention" in email messages originally sent to someone else or @mention symbol is a well known universal concept, there is little need to **not** draw attention to oneself, however it's not uncommon in such context to bracket [oneself] as editor or even embrace {yourself} pun intended [KJO]

> // Alice: you could try this [Bob SquarePants]

Such usage may depend on other syntax clashes. The hashtag was intended to use CamelCase as in this first case

> If case acceptable
> `// Alice:#BobSquarepants Shall I exchange the stack here.`
>
> Else
>
> `// Alice:Bob=Did * you exchange the stack here.`
>
> Else
>
> `// Alice<Bob: I suggest you exchange stack here.`
>
> End case

- equally note I have used the = same as in triple tag structure

Comment: My suggestion was going to be `Alice<Bob` (or, perhaps, `Bob>Alice`) where `<` /`>` are read as 'from' and 'to'. Not necessarily obvious, but meaningful if they are thought of as arrows (and you could even use/allow `<-`/`->`).

Answer (score 1):

Your project is using the [at symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign) in a different way than Stack Exchange and social media; a more mainstream way would be

> `//Bob: @Alice Please continue here or please fix this error`

Note the lack of a space after the @ sign, and the fact that it's part of the *message*, not the *header*. Your symbolism could be interpreted as Bob directing a message 'at' Alice. But I doubt that there's a commonly accepted antonym for this.

What you *could* do is replace the @ symbol with something else that represents addressing, e.g. → (or `->` if it needs to be ASCII). It's very easy to see what the antonym of that symbol would be.

Comment: Interesting the arrow could be a solution. e.g. //Alice <- Bob ...

Comment: You mean someone not familiar with SE, or Twitter, or Instagram, or Facebook, or just about any other social media out there. I would say the odds of anyone in a team of developers not understanding this use would be exceedingly low.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Agreed 100%

Comment: I don't use Instagram and Facebook, so I never knew...